# instagram python api full list of followers

Tags: python, instagram-api

I'm using the instagram api for python and I'm trying to get a full list of followers.   While reading over the documents, it seemed like this was the way to get full list of users that I follow:

```
api.user_followed_by()[0]
```

It looked much shorter the 490 users I follow so I did the following:

```
len(api.user_followed_by()[0])
```

which turned out to be 43.

Is there any way to get the full list or is there a limit?  Am I missing something?

Comment: [This data is paginated](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram#data-retrieval), so you have to take care of that.

Comment: this is a duplicate - thank you Rafael